# Reading RSS in .NET Core 3.1 is not working

Tags: .net-core, rss, syndication-feed

I have very simple .NET Core Web Api code that worked before in .NET Core 2.2 but stopped working after upgrading to 3.1

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/news")]
public IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> GetNews(string source)
{
    var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create(source));
    return feed.Items;
}
```

I can invoke it by navigating to: https://localhost:5001/api/news?source=http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml

**In debug I can see it gets items just fine, but throws this error returning them, I don't understand why it stopped working after I upgraded to 3.1 and how to fix it**

please advice, thanks!

[image]
[image]

> System.NotSupportedException: The collection type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName,System.String]' on 'System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationItem.AttributeExtensions' is not supported.
>      at System.Text.Json.JsonClassInfo.GetElementType(Type propertyType, Type parentType, MemberInfo memberInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.JsonClassInfo.CreateProperty(Type declaredPropertyType, Type runtimePropertyType, Type implementedPropertyType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Type parentClassType, JsonConverter converter, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.JsonClassInfo.AddProperty(Type propertyType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Type classType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.JsonClassInfo..ctor(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetOrAddClass(Type classType)
>      at System.Text.Json.JsonClassInfo.get_ElementClassInfo()
>      at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
>      at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Your error shows that you have an issue with `System.Text.Json` API, which is built-in in ASP.NET Core 3.x. Try to switch back to `Newtonsoft.Json` library

Comment: I never used explicitly System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json, these 2 lines of code is all I have, I cannot switch back since I never switched forward :)

Comment: `System.Text.Json` is default JSON serializer in ASP.NET Core 3.x [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview) article tells you a more

Comment: I know what it is :) I said I never explicitly use it in my code. You see these 2 lines of code in my post? That is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **default** JSON serializer in .NET Core 3.x is changed to `System.Text.Json`. In this case, you may need to specify to use `Newtonsoft.Json` as the default serializer (the default serializer in older versions of .NET Core).

In `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    // other settings in ConfigureServices...
}
```